# Laravel Subdomain Routing in a Subdirectory

Tags: laravel, routes, subdomain

I have Laravel 4.2 setup in a sub-directory on my localhost. So, my URL's are something like `http://account.localhost/projectName`

Everything works fine, until I try using `link_to_route()`... Instead of linking to, for example, `http://jdoe.localhost/projectName/post/some-slug` it's linking to `http://jdoe.localhost/post/some-slug`

I have a feeling that it has to do with my routes...

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.localhost'], function () {
    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'index', 'uses' => 'AccountsController@index']);
    Route::get('/posts/{slug}', ['as' => 'account.posts', 'uses' => 'PostsController@index']);
});

Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@showHome']);
```

If I change the domain to `{subdomain}.localhost/projectName`, it no longer recognizes the subdomain and just sends me to the homepage...

---

I saw that 4.2 implemented a method `forceRootUrl()` but wasn't sure how to use it. So, I ended up going with this:

```
/**
 * Handle routes to dynamic subdomains
 */

Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.' . Config::get('app.url')], function () {
    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'index', 'uses' => 'AccountsController@index']);

    Route::group(['prefix' => dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])], function () {
        Route::get('/posts/{slug}', ['as' => 'account.post', 'uses' => 'PostsController@index']);
        // related routes will go here
    });
});


/**
 * Main site routes
 */

Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@showHome']);
```

I consider this to be more of a hack than a solution, so I'm not going to post it as an answer. If anyone else has a better fix, I'd love to hear it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `prefix`:

```
Route::group(
    ['domain' => '{subdomain}.localhost', 'prefix' => 'projectName'],
    function () {
        Route::get('/posts/{slug}', ['as' => 'account.posts', 'uses' => 'projectName\\PostsController@index']);
});
```

Then use a `namespace` like:

```
namespace projectName;

class PostsController extends baseController {
    //...
}
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but not sure you understood the issue. projectName is not dynamic, it's the base directory of my site. The public folder is basicallt `C:\xampp\htdocs\projectName\public` Nonetheless, I tried it and it didn't work. It made everything go to my homepage again.

Comment: Isn't your directory structure looks like `projectName\PostsController`? Did you run `composer dump-autoload`? Are you using `subdomain.localhost/projectName/posts..` as `url` ?

Comment: I have the default project structure, my controllers are within `projectName/app/controllers`. When I go to `subdomain.localhost/projectName/` the links on the page that should point to the posts are instead linking to `subdomain.localhost/posts/slug`

Comment: Sorry! it was for `app/controllers/projectName` directory structure.

Comment: So I should remove the namespace? Still doesn't work. Any other suggestions? And yes, I ran `composer dump-autoload`